# Desktop App with Django, DRF, Vue 3 JS, Electron JS and Forge Electron - links out of the package error on make

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, electron

What I am trying to do:
Build and package a very simple desktop app using:

- Python Django as a backend (with Django Rest Framework for a rest api)
- Vue 3 js for the frontend (using Axios to consume the API)
- Electron JS to make it a desktop app and Forge Electron to package it.
- I am using a virtual env for the Django app (pyenv).

The build and run works perfectly: the app just fetch a list of posts from Django using DRF endpoints and a GET request from the Vue App.

The issue is when I want to make a package and deploy it.
Forge Electron comes with an error:

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:links out of the package.

And more specifically:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: /var/folders/3v/kk4yh47x7hlgs8rv94dxnx700000gn/T/electron-packager/tmp-2YhdSt/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/python/.venv/bin/python: file "../../../../../../../../../../../../Users/macbookpro/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3.10" links out of the package
```

I have tried multiple things I have found browsing:

1. set asar:false --> it complains that it needs to be true or an object
2. see if the issue was linked to node.js libs --> I found something about node-gyp bit it seems not relating to the issue.

The issue seems to be linked to where Python is located...
If that is the case, how to make Python "parf of" the package ?

I also thought of packaging the Django app (using pyinstaller for example), but again, not much resources about that either that I can find...

The way I did it was to create a Electron app first, then add vue js.
And then I have created a folder I called 'python', created a virtual env inside and installed Django and DRF.

Thank you.